# Variant of a record in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, record

I want to declare a variant type in OCaml

```
type 'a tree = Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree * int | Null
```

But there are a lot of properties here so I'd like to label them, so I tried using a record here:

```
type 'a tree = Node of { left: 'a tree; value: 'a; right:'a tree; height: int | Null
```

But this throws a syntax error.

Using something record like would allow me to use nice syntax

```
match x with
| Node of a -> a.value
| Null -> 0
```

How should I declare it not to get syntax errors?

Comment: This construction should be available in the next OCaml release, see http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5528

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could declare two mutually recursive types, one for the nodes and one for the trees:

```
# type 'a node = { left: 'a tree; value: 'a; right:'a tree; height: int } 
   and 'a tree = Node of 'a node | Null
  ;;
type 'a node = { left : 'a tree; value : 'a; right : 'a tree; height : int; } and 'a tree = Node of 'a node | Null;;

# match Node({left = Null; value = 1; right = Null; height = 0}) with
    | Node(n) -> n.value
    | Null -> 0
  ;;
- : int = 1
```